# Database Connection SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, windows-server

My payroll application developed in ASP.net and C language not able to connect the database. Our Payroll is broadcast through IIS, after we change our router i can't access this TimeCardUploader.
How can I Reconnect my Database?

[image]

Every time I re-start the application I see this error.

```
A Connection was successfully established with the server,.
but then an error occurred during the login process.
(provider: Shared Memory Provider, error:0-No process is on the other end of the pipe
```

And our biometric server is stopped.

Thank you.

Best Regard.

Comment: Please check database status, whether it's available or down?

Comment: It says, " A Connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occured during the login process. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error:0-No process is on the other end of the pipe"

And our biometric server is stopped, Everytime i try to restart, it stop

Comment: Check whether the SQL login you are using to connect database is enabled.

Comment: Did you check SQL Login? whether it's enabled or disabled?

Comment: where can i check that sir?,

Comment: Run > ssms > Put server name/ ip address in **Server Name**. Enter login id and password if you are using SQL Server Authentication. If you are using Windows Authentication you account should have access to SQL Server and necessary permission. Click on **Connect**.

Comment: Go to **Security** folder in Object Explorer at the left side. expand **Logins** folder. Right click on the login id you are using in Payroll application, click to **Properties** option. In the login properties windows, go to **Status** tab. Here you can see login status.

Comment: Its all enable sir, but i can't find the biostar server, it has biostar server configuration but it says there that the server need to start but when i try to start "Cannot start the biostar server"

Comment: Please share complete details Sir, Step by step. Or is there another way to connect/help you.

Answer (score 0):

First check if SQL Server is up and running on the database server.

If yes, then check if Shared memory/TCP-IP/Named pipes protocol is enabled on SQL Server. You can check that in SQL Server configuration manager. If it is not, then you have to enable it and then restart SQL Server service.

Also if you are using SQL login to connect to database, then you have to check if mixed mode authentication is enabled on SQL Server. To check that connect to SQL Server and right click on instance and go to properties -> security tab -> check if mixed mode authentication is enabled or not. This will again require SQL Server service restart to get the change reflected.

Check these 3 things first and let me know if it does not resolve your problem.

Please mark this solution as Solution, if it resolves your issue.

Comment: I just check the details sir, the all the pipes was already enabled, the mix mode is on, but in the server manager it is stop even if i try to start it won't start